# Syntax error in JSP

Tags: html, forms

Any one Please solve this error.
I am getting error in the Select Query it seems,but i am not getting and one more error is missing braces in the following code.As i need to fetch the details from another jsp page by taking username as primary key

```
enter code here

  <%@page import ="java.sql.*" %>
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>


 <%


 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 /","root","scott");
 Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select *from come2links.user_details  where USerName="+requestgetParameter("uName"));

 //int count=1;

 while(rs.next())
 {
  String FisrtName=rs.getString("FirstName");
  String LastName=rs.getString("LastName");
  Date dob = rs.getDate("DOB");
  String address=rs.getString("Address");
  String UserName=rs.getString("UserName");
  String Password=rs.getString("Password");
  //int Salary=rs.getInt("sal");
 %>

%>


 <form name="updatef1" action="" >


 First name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%=FisrtName%>"/>
 <br>
 Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<%=LastName%>"/>
 <br>
 DOB:<br>
 <input type="text" name="DOB" value="<%=dob%>"/>
 <br>
 Address:<br>
 <input type="text" name="Address" value="<%=address%>"/>
<br>
UserName:<br> 
<input type="text" name="UserName" value="<%=UserName%>" readonly/>
<br>
 Password:<br>
 <input type="text" name="Password" value="<%=Password%>"/>
 <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
  <br>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are missing a space in your SQL query, between the '*' and 'from'. You may also add some single quotes and your were clause if USerName is type of String/varchar, like this: where USerName='"+requestgetParameter("uName")+"'". I just want to warn you about the poor implementation of putting logic code into a view. It would be better to implement a MVC pattern, where the Model will be in charge of requesting the database. Also your code is unreliable as SQL injection may be done quite easily by an unapropriate use of the uName request parameter.